# Flutter :Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') while accessing document id from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the document id of my collection "blogs" in firebase . I tried to access it using id method but it is showing an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`.How can I access the document id?

this is how I tried to print the document id  `print(docRef.id);` but getting the error .What's wrong with my code?

```
DocumentReference docRef =
                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('blogs')
                                .add({
                                  'title': titleController.text,
                                  'body': myController.text,
                                  'author': name,
                                 
                                  'date': DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm')
                                      .format(DateTime.now()),
                                })
                                .then((value) => successAlert(context))
                                .catchError((error) => errorAlert(context));

                       print(docRef.id);

                        titleController.clear();
                        myController.clear();
                      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the data after `FirebaseFirestore` method you need to use this approach instead of using `then` method:

```
DocumentReference docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('blogs').add({
    'title': titleController.text,
    'body': myController.text,
    'author': name,
    'date': DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm').format(DateTime.now()),})
   .catchError((error) => errorAlert(context));

successAlert(context)
print(docRef.id);
titleController.clear();
myController.clear();
```

when you use `then` to get an `async` value you only get that result inside `then` and can't access it after `then`.

Answer (score 1):

well, while you're using `then`, try this instead :

```
                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection('blogs')
                                .add({
                                  'title': titleController.text,
                                  'body': myController.text,
                                  'author': name,
                                 
                                  'date': DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm')
                                      .format(DateTime.now()),
                                })
                             .then((value) {
                             print(value.id); // do it here
                             successAlert(context);
                             })
                                .catchError((error) => errorAlert(context));
```